# How to detect google play licensed user email

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

i wanna ask you how can i get User Email from LVL if app is licensed?
I need it to create some files on FTP for storing files.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a way create files strictly for that user, accessible by the same app, you can get the userId as part of the `ResponseData`

One possible way is to implement your own `Policy` and provide access to the `ResponseData` object returned by `processServerResponse`. `userId` is a property of `ResponseData`

```
public ResponseData getResponseData(){
    return mResponseData;
}

public void processServerResponse(int response, ResponseData rawData) {
    mResponseData = rawData;

    // set last response
    mLastResponse = response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot get any details for licensee.

Comment: is there any way i can get playstore default email address from system? :D

Comment: like customer's email? No.

Comment: yes, let's say you buy it, after LVL run, i would like to get your play store email address and use it on ftp

Comment: you cannot get customer detail. period. you need it? ask customer to provide it. or generate ie unique id for order and use that

Comment: and how can i generate a unique id? now i ask the customer for email, but you can type my email so you will, somehow, be able to access some of my data :))

Comment: You asked if you can get user Email from LVL. Answer is "No, you can't". End of story. :) Accept my answer (here's [link how to do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), as there's nothing to discuss further - you can't get customer details - like it or not. How to solve your other problem is subject of another questions.

Comment: It used to be possible in the old Google Checkout system, then they killed it. There's reverse lookup though - you can find users in Wallet console by e-mail.